# Multiple values from wordpress postmeta table keys

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, wordpress, google-maps

I have a feeling this is much easier than I am making it. Have a Google API Map and I can get the street address and zip code for one location from WordPress postmeta to place a marker. I can also get multiples of one metakey values (like property_address) which is not enough information for the Google API. So how to I get multiples of two metakey values? In my example every property_address and property_zip keys from the same post_ID? Currently I have like 50 locations already in the table.

```
var address = "<?php echo $property_address; ?>, <?php echo $property_zip; ?>";
```

That's easy enough to get one location for one pin. And I can hard code locations and get those to print out just by iterating through the hard code.

```
var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < address.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(address[i][1], address[i][2]),
    map: map
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
  return function() {
    infowindow.setContent(address[i][0]);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
```

So I guess I am asking, "How do I iterate through the postmeta table and find all of the data I need to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Just needed to loop through the results - but you knew that. So did I.